# Solution for private keys on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

I have to manage several servers, with services that can be cron, and integration jobs, deployments, backups. The common thing with all of these, is that they sometimes require access to other servers.

**Problem**: I don't want to spread my private key to all of these servers for obvious reasons.

I love agent forwarding and keychain.sh, but this requires me to keep connection open all the time to those servers.

A solution to this could be putting a private key on just one server, and then keeping connections open to all remote servers (with tmux/screen). But this is not ideal.

Another solution might be putting a very strong pass phrase on the private key and actually distributing it across these servers, but that is also not ideal.

Are there any other options I am overlooking?

Comment: So, each server might sometimes require access to another server to run a job? And you don't want to just generate different private keys on the other servers and distribute them to eachother? A.K.A. `node1 pub1 => node{2..5}` and `node2 pub2 => node1 & node{3..5}`, etc...? Or a different private key then the one you are connecting with to these servers put on each server? So you aren't using yours.

Comment: @DevNull Having a lot of keys is not really a manageable solution. Especially in the case of cloud computing, where servers are disposable.

Comment: True, which is why you find ways to manage those things like [`puppet`](https://puppetlabs.com/) which makes those things super easy. It is also simple to have a script generate a key-pair on cloud server and add it to all your relevant other servers. Both of these are more secure and better options than agent forwarding or keep-alive connections (IMO). Just some food for thought. I use two 'master' servers that once I `ssh` into I can access any other node in my cluster. Also with puppet I can easily manage ssh keys between servers.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two truly keyless and passwordless ways you can do this, though both are suboptimal.  After the section break, I'll show you just how easy this is to do with SSH keys.

**Method 1:** NFS or something like it.  A common filesystem would let you dump files in dedicated areas and then pick them up in cron jobs from the relevant systems.  This is, however, only as secure as your network filesystem.

**Method 2:** RLOGIN. SSH inherits a lot from from RSH, which allows a user with the same username and password (and salt?) on different systems to connect between them directly, no password (or key) needed (basically, the hash from `/etc/shadow` is used as proof).  I'm not sure if SSH can easily do this, and I unfortunately do not know of any guides on how to set that up.

---

For proper security, you'll need a private key on each server.  I see in the comments that you do not want to maintain all of that, but this is largely unavoidable.  Generating and throwing away private keys should be easy to do, as should adding them as `authorized_keys` on the systems they need to grant access to.

Even if we're talking about a hundred systems, key generation could be scripted in this kind of manner from your personal system (This assumes you already have root access from your personal system):

```bsh
cd /tmp
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
for server in node{1..100}; do
  echo "Generating key for $server..."
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "root@$server" -k .ssh/id_rsa
  cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
  scp -pr .ssh root@$server:
  rm .ssh/id_rsa*
  sleep 1
done
for server in node{1..100}; do
  cat authorized_keys |ssh root@$server "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
done
```

I used `sleep 1` because all of those keys are getting generated on the same system; this is a sanity check to ensure that you get more randomness.  Two loops were needed because we need each pubkey before we can share the list of authorized keys.

There, now you have a hundred servers, named node1 to node100, each with a key granting root access to root on each other server.

(Note, I don't advocate for allowing users to log in as root.  The `sudo` tool allows far better control and accountability.  For the above script to work, you'd have to either add your pubkey to root's authorized_keys on each node or else you'd need sudo `NOPASSWD` access and a few revisions to my code (e.g. `scp -pr .ssh $server:/tmp && ssh $server "sudo chown root:root /tmp/.ssh && sudo mv /tmp/.ssh /root/"`).